# Determine and Grab a Number Within Directory Name and Use That Number In an Expression

Tags: powershell, scripting

What I need to do is create a variable that can do an `ls` of a directory, find the directories with a specific naming convention, determine the highest number within these directories (each directory will end with a `_#`), and then increment that number by one to create the next directory.

For example:

`ls c:\` outputs:

```
c:\ABC
c:\foo1
c:\foo2
```

I need to create `c:\foo3` since `c:\foo2` is the highest currently. So I need to determine what the highest directory is and then create a new directory with the next incremental number.

I got pieces of all of this working, but I cannot get anything to work together.

Comment: Show us the code you have pieced together so far. Explain what you expect the code to do, and what it does differently than what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$nextIndex = 1 + (
  (Get-ChildItem -Directory C:\foo*[0-9]).Name -replace '^.*\D' |
    Measure-Object -Maximum
).Maximum

New-Item -Type Directory C:\foo${nextIndex}
```

- `(Get-ChildItem -Directory C:\foo*[0-9]).Name` returns the names of all directories in `C:\` whose names start with `foo` and end in (at least) one digit.
- `-replace '^.*\D'` removes everything but the number at the end from each name.
- `Measure-Object -Maximum` then determines the maximum among the resulting number-only strings (PowerShell automatically converts the strings to numbers when determining the maximum).
- `1 + (...).Maximum` therefore returns the highest number currently embedded in the directory names incremented by one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt. It may not be as concise as [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)'s answer but I think it will do what you want.

It finds all folders with a sequence number inside the given path (1 level) and creates new folders with the same name but with a higher trailing number.

```
$path = 'C:\'                                                                           #'# (dummy comment to fix broken syntax highlighting)
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\d+$' } |               # find only folders with a name that ends in a number
    Group-Object -Property { $_.Name -replace '\d+$'} |    # group these folders by their name without the trailing number
    ForEach-Object {                                       # go through all the groups
        $baseName  = $_.Name                               # the group name is the base name for the new folder

        # get the name of the folder in the group with the highest number
        # create a new folder with the same base name and the next sequence number
        $lastUsed  = ($_.Group | Sort-Object {[int]($_.Name -replace $baseName)} -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Name
        $nextIndex = [int]([regex]'\d+$').Match($lastUsed).Value + 1
        $newFolder = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('{0}{1}' -f $baseName, $nextIndex)

        Write-Host "Creating directory '$newFolder'"
        New-Item -Path $newFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }
```

So if you have these folders in your root path:

```
123ABC_1
bar1
foo1
foo2
```

The result will be:

```
123ABC_1
123ABC_2
bar1
bar2
foo1
foo2
foo3
```